# Create new nested routes with different content with vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I am trying to make a recommendation app that is embedded in customers page which fetches the products and shows recommended products related to what user looked at.

When clicked it shows one product(main) and below the related products. When user clicked one of the related products, **I want to nest it to url and the main product will be the clicked related product so the related products will be changed.**

User may click another related product on new nested page which will be again nested again and so on. URL will be like this:

main-page > related1(id) > related2(id) > related3(id) ...

**So that the user can go back and forth on the products. I have button to go around the "history".** Also the information will change so I thought using "props, slots, queries, route params or state. I don't know which one I should use.

[image: Nested pages with different data]

I tried router-link with params and query. I tried pushing router to URL manually. I tried storing the product id in state and tried calling it with async everytime user visit that page but I couldn't figure out the nested URL part.

Comment: Did you already consider using [addRoute](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#addroute)?

Comment: @Tino Thanks for the reply. I saw but I couldn't add it for some reason.

Comment: Would you mind adding this attempt (with some code snippets) to the question? Maybe there is the path to the solution.